when i upload project on vercel there was dependency error
[20:34:37.402] Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
[20:34:37.686] Cloning github.com/sukanta1234/Education (Branch: main, Commit: fc54bbc)
[20:34:38.319] Previous build cache not available
[20:34:38.352] Cloning completed: 664.649ms
[20:34:38.654] Running "vercel build"
[20:34:39.093] Vercel CLI 34.1.10
[20:34:39.934] Installing dependencies...
[20:34:41.881] npm notice
[20:34:41.882] npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.5.0 -> 10.7.0
[20:34:41.882] npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.7.0%5C>
[20:34:41.882] npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.7.0` to update!
[20:34:41.882] npm notice
[20:34:41.883] npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
[20:34:41.886] npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
[20:34:41.887] npm ERR!
[20:34:41.887] npm ERR! While resolving: react-html-parser@2.0.2
[20:34:41.887] npm ERR! Found: react@18.3.1
[20:34:41.887] npm ERR! node_modules/react
[20:34:41.888] npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
[20:34:41.888] npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.11.4
[20:34:41.888] npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
[20:34:41.888] npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.11.4" from the root project
[20:34:41.888] npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.11.5
[20:34:41.889] npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
[20:34:41.889] npm ERR!       @emotion/styled@"^11.11.5" from the root project
[20:34:41.889] npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system)
[20:34:41.889] npm ERR!     4 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, react-select)
[20:34:41.889] npm ERR!   28 more (@emotion/styled, ...)
[20:34:41.890] npm ERR!
[20:34:41.890] npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
[20:34:41.890] npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-0" from react-html-parser@2.0.2
[20:34:41.890] npm ERR! node_modules/react-html-parser
[20:34:41.890] npm ERR!   react-html-parser@"^2.0.2" from the root project
[20:34:41.890] npm ERR!
[20:34:41.891] npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
[20:34:41.891] npm ERR! node_modules/react
[20:34:41.895] npm ERR!   peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0-0" from react-html-parser@2.0.2
[20:34:41.895] npm ERR!   node_modules/react-html-parser
[20:34:41.895] npm ERR!     react-html-parser@"^2.0.2" from the root project
[20:34:41.895] npm ERR!
[20:34:41.895] npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
[20:34:41.895] npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
[20:34:41.895] npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
[20:34:41.896] npm ERR!
[20:34:41.896] npm ERR!
[20:34:41.896] npm ERR! For a full report see:
[20:34:41.896] npm ERR! /vercel/.npm/_logs/2024-05-15T15_04_40_269Z-eresolve-report.txt
[20:34:41.896]
[20:34:41.896] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /vercel/.npm/_logs/2024-05-15T15_04_40_269Z-debug-0.log
[20:34:41.907] Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
[20:34:42.141]
please send solution
